# How to use Excel TEXTJOIN to join all rows in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im trying to use the textjoin function in excel.
I have a column A, in a table so I want to use TEXTJOIN to make it as Row1,Row2...Rown
When I use =TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;A:A) then I get all the values, including the header.
When I try =TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;A2:A) to skip header, I get a name error

Using =ADDRESS(ROWS(tablename);1;4;1), I get the cell reference of the last record. But unable to pass this through into the TEXTJOIN function itself. Any help please?

Comment: But if it's a table just select the data without header...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have no content in column **A** below the table, consider:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A2:A1048576)
```

Because `TEXTJOIN()` can skip blanks, it is not necessary to determine the table's last row.

**However:**

If we have a *Named Table* that

- may start on any row and
- may start on any column and
- may have "junk" both above and below the Table
- but we know the Table's Name

then:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,Table1[Head1])
```

[image]

may

Answer (score 0):

If Column A contains text values...

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(REPT("z",255),A:A,1)))
```

If Column A contains numerical values...

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,A:A,1)))
```